# ng-image-slider imageSize

Tags: angular, slider, styles

I'm using [ng-image-slider](https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider) for a image carousel in angular, as following:

```
<ng-image-slider
  class="slider"
  [images]="images"
  [infinite]="true"
  [imageSize]="{width: '762px', height: 442, space: 10}"
  [autoSlide]="false"
></ng-image-slider>
```

But somehow, the `width` of each image remains 205px as the default.
The weird thing is, that this default is added to `element.style` in the DOM by default when loading the app, but once I change the screen size (e.g via chrome devtools) I suddenly get my custom width.

The DOM element when loading:

```
<div class="img-div image-popup ng-star-inserted" style="width: 205px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
```

The DOM element after trigger screen size changing:

```
   <div class="img-div image-popup ng-star-inserted" style="width: 762px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
```

Note the width difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

take a look this demo from the GIT doc of the library:

```
https://sanjayv.github.io/ng-image-slider/
```

You just have to change the width from [image-size] to numbers (without 'px')

```
[imageSize]="{width: 742, height: 442, space: 10}"
```

Best,